# How to call function from OnExecute method of dojo ConfimDialog

Tags: dojo

I have delete button on my Feature. When I click on DELETE, below function will call and Confirm dialog box  should come, if I select OK it should delete document, If I cancel, it should be canceled.

```
console.log("before confirm dialog");

myDialog = new ConfirmDialog({
  title: "ConfirmDialog",
  content: "Are you sure? You want to delete document.",
  style: "width: 400px, color: green",
  onCancel: function(){
    //Called when user has pressed the Dialog's cancel button, to notify container.
    console.log("cancel");
  },
  onExecute: function(){
    //Called when user has pressed the dialog's OK button, to notify container.
    console.log("OK----");
    // getting error undefined for this function. How to call this ?
    this.onClickResetButton();
  }
});

  myDialog.show();
};
```

Comment: Please be clear on what you are actually trying to accomplish, it will help you get a more accurate answer and prevent confusion. Thanks and welcome to SO!

Comment: Are you creating this confirme inside a widget , class, so you're using AMD or not ?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.onClickResetButton() method inside `onExecute` is undefined because 'this' refers to the context of your dialog. i.e. it thinks that `onClickResetButton()` is a method which is part of `ConfirmDialog`
```

one way to overcome this is define a variable (may be in constructor or postCreate) and assign 'this' to it

ex: `let widgetRef=this;`

later you can use `widgetRef.onClickResetButton()` inside '`onExecute`'